# ajax jquery php: w3school example jquery ajax post not displaying suggestion

Tags: php, jquery, post

I tried the following code from w3schools. When I enter letters in a input txt box, suggestions should get displayed accordingly. However, nothing is getting displayed as suggestion. I'm not able to get the txt value with serialize.
In gethint.php, since it is a post request, i changed the original  $q=$_GET["q"]; to $q=$_POST["q"].
Can someone tell me on what i'm doing wrong? thank you.

post_example.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    // txt=$("input").val();
    txt=$("input").serialize();
    $.post("gethint.php",txt,function(result){
      $("span").html(result);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
First name:

<input type="text" >
<p>Suggestions: <span></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

gethint.php

```
<?php
 // Fill up array with names
 $a[]="Anna";
 $a[]="Brittany";
 $a[]="Cinderella";
 $a[]="Diana";
 $a[]="Eva";
 $a[]="Fiona";
 $a[]="Gunda";
 $a[]="Hege";
 $a[]="Inga";
 $a[]="Johanna";
 $a[]="Kitty";
 $a[]="Linda";
 $a[]="Nina";
 $a[]="Ophelia";
 $a[]="Petunia";
 $a[]="Amanda";
 $a[]="Raquel";
 $a[]="Cindy";
 $a[]="Doris";
 $a[]="Eve";
 $a[]="Evita";
 $a[]="Sunniva";
 $a[]="Tove";
 $a[]="Unni";
 $a[]="Violet";
 $a[]="Liza";
 $a[]="Elizabeth";
 $a[]="Ellen";
 $a[]="Wenche";
 $a[]="Vicky";

 //get the q parameter from URL
 $q=$_POST["q"];

 //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
 if (strlen($q) > 0)
   {
   $hint="";
   for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
     {
     if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
       {
       if ($hint=="")
         {
         $hint=$a[$i];
         }
       else
         {
         $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
         }
       }
     }
   }

 // Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
 // or to the correct values
 if ($hint == "")
   {
   $response="no suggestion";
   }
 else
   {
   $response=$hint;
   }

 //output the response
 echo $response;
 ?>
```

Comment: try this `<input type="text" name="q" value="">`

Comment: You really should stop using w3schools site. For reasons "why", read here: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missed, the `q` in your line

```
$.post("gethint.php",txt,function(result){
```

should be

```
$.post("gethint.php", {q: txt},function(result){
```

or if you are using `serialize` then use the name of the input box like

```
<input type="text" name="q" >
```

Comment: Ok, your 2nd solution (for serialize) works but it doesn't work when i use txt=$("input").val(); and $.post("gethint.php?q=".txt,function(result){

Answer (score 1):

The input doesn't have a name, so when you `serialize` it you get an empty string back.